# APIM ARM based customization of OpenApi 'front-end' with REST to SOAP deployment

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a WCF backend service which is a SOAP/XML service and I need to expose it to my consumers. 
Importing the WSDL is not a problem, but I don't like the naming/url of the operations which is based on the SoapAction in the WSDL.

Manually I can change the display name, URL and HTTP verb to make it more 'restful' on the outside, but is there a way to automate this?
I like to add this to my ARM template somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change how WSDL import works, but it's only a batch operation of sorts. If you generate ARM template after you imported WSDL you will be able to use it to recreate your API without source WSDL. And you will be able to change that template however you see fit.

Comment: I can remember to find api definition, products etc in the generated ARM template via 'Automation script', but that seems no longer the case? Or am I looking in the wong spot?

Comment: They should be in generated template, just checked and both products and APIs are there.